# How to prevent executing an ajax function too often

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function go_save(){
  console.log('saving...');
}

$('button').on('click', function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  //the above should be written each time the button is clicked
  //the next should be executed only if the last click happens 9 seconds in the past
  go_save();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

`go_save` is an ajax function and I want to prevent it to execute if a user clicks on a button several times at once.

But I don't want to wait for `console.log('clicked')`, only for `go_save()`

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You should not do it manually, I will suggest you to disable the button after clicking and enable the button again when the ajax request is complete.*

You can check the time differences in seconds in each click of the button. You can ignore the time check for the first click with a flag variable:

```js
function go_save(){
  console.log('saving...');
  time = new Date();
  isFirst = false;
}
var time = new Date();
var isFirst = true;
$('button').on('click', function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  //the above should be written each time the button is clicked
  //the next should be executed only if the last click happens 9 seconds in the past
  var diff = (new Date().getTime() - time.getTime()) / 1000;
  if(isFirst || diff >= 9)
    go_save();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: did you try? both functions are executed immediatelly

Comment: @qadenza, it is happening only for the first click which I think logical, if do not want then simply remove the flag variable checking like `if(diff >= 9).....`:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a debounce function like this:

```js
function go_save(){
  console.log('saving...');
}

const debouncedFunction = debounce(go_save, 1000);

$('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    debouncedFunction();
});

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
 var timeout;
 return function() {
  var context = this, args = arguments;
  var later = function() {
   timeout = null;
   if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
  };
  var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
 };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: seems you copied it from [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

Comment: I dont want to wait for `console.log('clicked')`, only for `go_save()`

Comment: Edited to fit your requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout method:

Edit as per comments:

```
let clicker = 0;
$('button').on('click', function(){
  ++clicker;
  console.log('clicked');
  if (clicker == 1) {
    setTimeout(function() { // once button clicked, execute go_save() after 9 seconds.
      go_save();
      clicker = 0;
    }, 9000);
  }
});
```

Old answer:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
console.log('clicked');
this.disabled = true; // disabled the clicked button 
setTimeout(function() { // remove it after 9 seconds
        this.disabled = false;
    }, 9000);
//the above should be written each time the button is clicked
//the next should be executed only if the last click happens 9 seconds in the past
go_save();
});
```

read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: read the question again. I dont want to wait for `console.log('clicked')`, only for `go_save()`

Comment: @qadenza the ajax execute when clicking the button. If you prevent the button from clicking to often (9 seconds in this example) it will do the job, dosen't it?

Comment: once again -  I dont want to wait for `console.log('clicked')`, only `for go_save()`

Comment: Sorry for this question but do you want to let user click button as many time he wants and to execute `go_save()` once in 9 seconds?

Comment: yes, because that click has another function on the page which should be executed immediatly. Only `go_save` should be waiting

Comment: @qadenza Is that what you try to achieve?

Comment: no, after 9 seconds `go_save` is executed not only once but as much times as the button is clicked

Comment: When you explain slow i understand fast (: Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use `async` property in your ajax request. It will wait until your request complete.

See example -

```
           $.ajax({
                url: base_url+pageUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { },  
                async: false,
                success: function(response){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#'+responseDiv).empty().html(response.template);
                    }, 500);
                },
                error: function(){
                    toastr.error("Something went wrong, but we're here to help! Reach out to <a href='mailto:helpdesk@nhpowerhour.com'>helpdesk@nhpowerhour.com</a> We're here for you!");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do something much big. just disabled the button until the work has been finished.here is the code bellow

```js
function go_save(){

  console.log('saving...');
  $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
}

const debouncedFunction = debounce(go_save, 1000);

$('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    $('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
    debouncedFunction();

});

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
 var timeout;
 return function() {
  var context = this, args = arguments;
  var later = function() {
   timeout = null;
   if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
  };
  var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);

 };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

I hope this will help you. if you have any questions you can as me anytime.

thank you.

Sagar Kumar, Software Developer

Comment: if you disabled the button then how a user can click button multiple times.